# Descriptografar código Java Script, preciso mudar url e não estou encontrando

Tags: javascript, jquery, script

Esse codigo esta criptografado? peguei esse código de um outro site, ele é um popup, ele puxa as pagina de um site, Então pra eu colocar as pagina com o meus links preciso descobrir onde alterar, e desse jeito esta quase impossível pra mim, sou iniciante em programação, o que pode ser feito [Clique aqui para abrir o java script](http://yourjavascript.com/10163136111/popup.js)

Comment: Poste o código diretamente aqui, selecione-o e formate-o clicando em `{}`

Comment: O código é grande amigo, ultrapassando o limite de caracteres, mim ajuda no link aqui. [http://yourjavascript.com/10163136111/popup.js]

Comment: Mostre um exemplo,ou melhor, o site onde vc encontrou esse script, pelo que vi rapidamente no codigo ele faz uma varredura em uma pagina, encontrando tags.

Comment: @Benilto esse código está minificado se não me engano. Aconselho você a copiar esse código e colar em algum site que "converte" ele para um arquivo js normal.

Comment: @user57764 eu conseguir reverter para um arquivo normal; Tem como fazer essa alteração? ao invés de fazer a varredura por tag, usar os links diretamente, e pra ele fazer a varredura precisa de uma referencia de onde esta pegando, e não encontrei tbm, vou postar o código ja normal, [http://yourjavascript.com/180361102107/popup.js]

Comment: Eu conseguir converter e editar mas para o codigo funcionar precisar esta minificado igual antes, como faço pra deixar todo o codigo desse jeito? `7661722049734F6B30383434333539303235` @LeonardoCoelho

Comment: Eu conseguir converter e editar mas para o codigo funcionar precisar esta minificado igual antes, como faço pra deixar todo o codigo desse jeito? `7661722049734F6B30383434333539303235` @user57764

Comment: @Benilto você consegue encontrar sites que fazem essa minificação como o JSCompress por exemplo.Boa Sorte

Comment: Codifica esse código para deixar numérico e letra igual antes, igual citei nos comentários acima, já esta editado como queria, agora só falta Codificar pra o codigo funcionar, Segue o codigo: (https://jsfiddle.net/Benilto/1mm2cb57)

Answer (score 2):

Use um Javascript Beautifier, como o: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Copie todo o código do javascript, cole no primeiro campo do jsbeautifier e depois clique em "Beautify JavaScript or HTML". Ele vai reformatar todo o código, com identação e tudo.

Porém as variáveis continuarão minificadas.